# How to bring data from DB of a User into form to update it

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, crud

I'm studying django and trying to make a simple CRUD, following the `djangoGirls` tutorial. But unfortunatelly they don't show how to UPDATE data.

I'm already `Inserting`, `Reading/listing` how may I `Delete` and `Update`?

I listed the users with a link to edit it:

```
{% extends 'bloodDonation/master.html' %}

{% block content %}
      <h1 class="center">LIST DONATORS<h1>
      <ul>
      {% for donator in donators %}
          <div class="row">
                  <div class="container">
                       <div class="col s12 blue-grey lighten-5 border_lighten">
                             <div class="col s12 m12 padding_normal">
                                    {{ donator.name }}
                                    <div id="icon" class="right">
                                           <a href="{% url 'edit_donator' %}" class="tooltipped" data-position="right" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Editar Dados""> <i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
                                    </div>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

As you can see, I have an `a` tag pointing to `edit_donator` url.
How may I pass the ID/data of the selected/clicked user so I can pull his data and throw it inside the form?

Form creation:

```
class EditDonatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
            model = Donator
            fields = [ 'name', 'age', 'email', 'phone', 'bloodType', 'observation' ]
```

Trying to pass the ID:

```
 url(r'^donator/(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$', views.edit_donator, name='edit_donator'),
```

How may I get data from database and already place it inside form so I can perform an `Update`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't require to send the data to another link. You can update the details on the same URL.

Change your HTML to this:

```
{% extends 'bloodDonation/master.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h1 class="center">LIST DONATORS<h1>
  <ul>
  {% for donator in donators %}
      <div class="row">
              <div class="container">
                   <div class="col s12 blue-grey lighten-5 border_lighten">
                         <div class="col s12 m12 padding_normal">
                                {{ donator.name }}
                                <div id="icon" class="right">
                                       <a href="yoururl/?edit-donator={{ donator.id }}" class="tooltipped" data-position="right" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Editar Dados""> <i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
                                </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
        </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

In your view write,

```
if 'edit-donator' in request.GET:
    edit_data = YourModel.objects.get(id=request.GET['edit-donator'])
    form = EditDonatorForm(instance=edit_data)
```

This will get the data from the model and pass it to the template.
Now you can perform the update.
Hope this helps :)